# API Manager - Send Mediator: "Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} java.lang.NumberFormatException: null"

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have 2 API as below and I am trying to invoke API2 from my API1 using SEND mediator but no response is returned and error is printed in logs:

API1 -

URL`https://localhost:8243/sendtest/1.0/{num}`

In Flow Sequence

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="send_mediator_test_in" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <property expression="get-property('uri.var.num')" name="uri.var.num" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <http method="get" uri-template="https://localhost:8243/protest/1.0/{uri.var.num}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>
```

API2 - (Prototyped)

URL`https://localhost:8243/protest/1.0/{num}`

Inline Script

```
mc.setProperty('CONTENT_TYPE', 'application/json');
var Num = mc.getProperty('uri.var.num');
mc.setPayloadJSON({ "NumberReturn": Num });
```

Response

```
{
    "NumberReturn": "100"
}
```

Invoking API1 with below environments works fine and proper response is returned.

```
OS: Windows 7
Java: 1.7.0_45
WSO2 AM: 2.0.0
```

But gets error with below environment

```
OS: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)
Java: 1.7.0_101
WSO2 AM: 2.0.0
```

Error while invoking API1

```
TID: [-1] [] [2017-02-03 06:34:23,265] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-02-03 06:34:23,265] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "a4[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-02-03 06:34:23,265] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2017-02-03 06:34:23,265] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 06:34:23,278] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool} -  Uncaught exception {org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool}
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:404)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:483)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.common.APIMgtLatencyStatsHandler.handleResponse(APIMgtLatencyStatsHandler.java:43)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:323)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:90)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:56)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:300)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:554)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:188)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:255)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 06:34:30,750]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.handler.ChannelCloseHandler} -  Received channel close for id 1 citing class 0 and method 0 {org.wso2.andes.server.handler.ChannelCloseHandler}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 06:34:30,750]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.AMQChannel} -  No consumers to unsubscribe on channel [/127.0.0.1:53226(admin):1] {org.wso2.andes.server.AMQChannel}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 06:34:30,750]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.kernel.FlowControlManager} -  Channel removed (ID: 127.0.0.1:53226) {org.wso2.andes.kernel.FlowControlManager}
TID: [-1234] [] [2017-02-03 06:34:30,752]  INFO {org.wso2.andes.server.handler.ConnectionCloseMethodHandler} -  ConnectionClose received with reply code/reply text 200/JMS client is closing the connection. for /127.0.0.1:53226(admin) {org.wso2.andes.server.handler.ConnectionCloseMethodHandler}
```

Please advise what is wrong.

Comment: Can you post the config of `inq/2.0` too?

Comment: @Bhathiya - inq/2.0 was an example API. I have added more details about both API and environment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a known issue](https://wso2.org/jira/browse/APIMANAGER-5483) in APIM 2.0.0 and is fixed in 2.1.0

This happens with prototype APIs or other APIs which does not have `APIAuthenticationHandler`, when you have analytics enabled. Maybe you have enable analytics in your Windows setup only.

As a workaround, put

```
<property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"/>
```

inside `inSequence` of your prototype API, like this.

```
<inSequence>
     <script language="js">your-js-goes-here</script>
     <property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"/>
...
...
<inSequence>
```

Comment: Thanks. Added <property expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"/> in the Sequence where I was using Send and all works fine now.